# Net CORE Keycloak and OIDC

Tags: asp.net-core, keycloak, openid

I tried to create .Net Core 3.1 Web API which used Keycloak authorization. I want to implement the following scenario:

Browser sends some request to API.

1. If user isn't authenticated, API redirects to Keycloak login page.
   API checks auth.
   API sends response.
   But it doesn't work

Into step 2 I have:

> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running your application on multiple instances behind a load-balancer, then you need to be sure that the same service instance is used through the entire authentication cycle. Otherwise you might the correlation error.

Comment: it's a unique application rest api

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your error is about as there was no configuration provided, but if you need to easily add KeyCloak authentication for your .Net Core backend you can use the following code (from package [Delobytes.AspNetCore.Infrastructure](https://github.com/a-postx/Delobytes.AspNetCore.Infrastructure/blob/master/README.en.md))

```
services.AddKeyCloakAuthentication("SchemeName", true, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://mykeycloakinstallation.com/auth/realms/myrealm"; //"issuer" endpoint
        options.Audience = "account";
        options.OpenIdConfigurationEndpoint = "https://mykeycloakinstallation.com/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationOptions
        {
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "https://mykeycloakinstallation.com/auth/realms/myrealm",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "account",
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
        };
    });
```